# Prove that $a_n$>$b_n$

Tags: calculus, inequality

For a given real number $\alpha>0$, define $a_n=(1^{\alpha}+2^{\alpha}+\dots+n^{\alpha})^{n}$ and $b_n=n^n(n!)^{\alpha}$, for $n=1,2,...$
Prove that $a_n>b_n$ for all $n>1$ 
There were powers present in the statement, therefore I tried to compare $log{(a_n)}$ and $log(b_n)$ but I couldn't come to any conclusion as such. Help

Comment: Try the AM-GM inequality.

Comment: @Nate It was so straightforward and I don't know what was I thinking! -_-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the [AM-GM inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AM-GM),
$$
\frac{1^\alpha+2^\alpha+\ldots+n^\alpha}n\ge\sqrt[n]{(n!)^\alpha}
$$
and
$$
(1^\alpha+2^\alpha+\ldots+n^\alpha)^n\ge n^n(n!)^\alpha.
$$

Answer (score 1):

Use the inequality between geometric and arithmetic means:$$a_n=(1^{\alpha}+2^{\alpha}+\dots+n^{\alpha})^{n}
= n^n \left(\frac{1^{\alpha}+2^{\alpha}+\dots+n^{\alpha}}n
\right)^{n}\ge 
n^n\prod_{k=1}^n k^{\alpha} = b_n.
$$